# CodeIgniter - Getting rid of the index.php in different circumstances

Tags: codeigniter

I have my CodeIgniter install one path back from the public_html directory so its not in the root of my web folder.

Can someone suggest .htaccess code that will get rid of the index.php in the URL based on this?

I have tried a few in the past and they havent worked, im quite stumped.

Cheers,

I have tried the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you put the index.php one folder back from public_html as well?

I would suggest not doing so, there should be no harm in making the index.php public, but well worth hiding the rest.

Put the index.php back under public_html and modify it like so:

Line 56:

```
$system_path = '../system';
```

Line 72:

```
$application_folder = '../application';
```

Of course if you have them in another folder then change the path accordingly.

EDIT:

Sorry I should note that afterwards your htaccess should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

*try* adding

`RewriteBase /public_html/`

above the first `RewriteCond`.

but I'm not an .haccess wizard by any means.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```